# Loop no Construtor c#

Tags: c#, hash, md5

Estou tentando settar a minha `Senha` usando o `md5`, porém esta ocorrendo um loop ao settar.

```
public class Usuario
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
    public string Senha {
        get { return Senha; }
        set { Console.WriteLine("valor"+value );
            this.Senha = CalculateMD5Hash(value); }
    }

    public static String CalculateMD5Hash(String input) {

            // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++) {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

A classe está chamando a função `CalculateMD5Hash` várias vezes como demosntrado abaixo.
E.g.: `value = 123`

```
value1 = 202CB962AC59075B964B07152D234B70 (hash do value)

value2 = D9840773233FA6B19FDE8CAF765402F5 (hash do value1)
```

Como eu paro o Loop e chamo a função de calcular o `MD5` apenas uma vez?

Comment: Por que não criar o hash dentro do loop e usar `.Append()` fora do loop?

Answer (score 1):

As propriedades não estavam definidas corretamentes. Pois o set e o get estavam chamando eles mesmos, de modo a causar overflow.

Pra resolver é necessário criar uma campo `backing field` para armazenar o valor da propriedade:

```
private string _senha;
public string Senha 
{
    get { return _senha; }
    set 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("valor"+value );
        _senha = CalculateMD5Hash(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aproveita e remove o método `CalculateMD5Hash` da classe `Usuario`. Está bem claro que não é responabilidade do *Usuario* em criptografar strings.

Answer (score 1):

Vitor, vou fugir completamente ao seu problema, mas quero lhe apontar um erro basico na sua solução.:

**Você está usando MD5 para armazenar uma Senha.**

Entenda, Nenhum algoritmo de hash, por maior que seja os blocos, por menor que seja a chance de colisão, não é seguro o suficiente para proteger uma senha.

Abaixo segue uma implementação que utilizei a algum tempo (Pbkdf2 + SHA512):

**Modelo do Banco de Dados**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usuario](
    [UsuarioGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [binary](64) NOT NULL,
    [Salt] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DataCriacao] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pessoa_DataCriacao]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pessoa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UsuarioGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note, que no exemplo acima eu armazeno a senha como um array de bytes de tamanho 64, e o Salt em um array de bytes de tamanho 16.

A função do Salt aqui é tornar a senha unica, mesmo que dois usuarios optem por utilizar a mesma senha.

**Entidade - Entity Framework**

```
[Table("Usuario")]
public partial class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UsuarioGUID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
}
```

**DTO**

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Usuario
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Guid UsuarioGUID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
}
```

Observe que na minha entidade eu tenho uma propriedade `byte[] Password` e outra chamada `byte[] Salt`, enquanto que na minha DTO tenho apenas o campo `string Password`.

**UsuarioController**

```
private byte[] CreateSalt()
{
    var salt = new byte[16];
    using (var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        provider.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return salt;
}

[HttpPut]
public async Task<int> Inserir(DTO.Pessoa dto)
{
    var entity = default(Models.Pessoa);
    try
    {
        var password = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512() {
            Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dto.Password)
        };
        entity = MapperConfig.Mapper.Map<Models.Pessoa>(dto);
        entity.Salt = this.CreateSalt();
        entity.Password = Pbkdf2.ComputeDerivedKey(password, entity.Salt, UInt16.MaxValue, password.HashSize / 8);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima eu utilizei o seguinte pacote do NuGet: [CryptSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/)

Na hora de comparar as senhas, você deve recuperar o `Salt` e chamar o método `Pbkdf2.ComputeDerivedKey` novamente passando os mesmos parametros.

Comment: Eu realmente tinha visto sobre o md5, mas como a aplicação é pra aprendizagem eu achei interessante somente criptografar de forma básica mesmo. 
A abordagem que você apresentou é bem interessante e vou aplica-lá tb. Vlw.